# NTRU HPS98 vs NTRU-HRSS-KEM vs new NTRU

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, nist, ntru

What is a simple explanation for the difference in terms of key gen, encryption and decryption between the original NTRU (HPS98) and the NTRU candidates submitted in NIST PQ Standardisation?

Round 1 - NTRU Encrypt, NTRU-HRSS-KEM, NTRU Prime

Round 2 - NTRU (Merger of NTRU Encrypt and NTRU-HRSS-KEM), NTRU Prime

For example, NTRU Encrypt in round 1 uses NAEP padding as compared to HPS98.

Paper by Schnack on "Comparison of NTRU Variants" talks more about the size/security rather than implementation itself. What other differences are there between HPS98 and the different NTRU Candidates?